# Java applet doesn't draw on mouse events

Tags: java, applet

this is the code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.applet.*;
import java.util.Vector;


public class PainterNN extends Applet implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener{

    class MyShape{
    int mx;
    int my;
    Color mc;

    MyShape(int x, int y, Color c){
        mx=x;
        my=y;
        mc=c;
        }

    void Render(Graphics g){
          g.setColor(mc);
        g.fillOval (mx,my,10,10);
        }
}


    Vector<MyShape> vec = new Vector();   


    public void init() {
        }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        for(int i =0; i < vec.size() ; i=i+1){

        MyShape s = vec.elementAt(i);
        s.Render(g);
        }
    }

    public void mouseEntered( MouseEvent e ) {
      // called when the pointer enters the applet's rectangular area
   }
           public void mouseExited( MouseEvent e ) {
      // called when the pointer leaves the applet's rectangular area
   }
           public void mouseClicked( MouseEvent e ) {
      // called after a press and release of a mouse button
      // with no motion in between
      // (If the user presses, drags, and then releases, there will be
      // no click event generated.)
   }
           public void mousePressed( MouseEvent e ) {  // called after a button is pressed down
      repaint();
      // "Consume" the event so it won't be processed in the
      // default manner by the source which generated it.
      e.consume();
   }
   public void mouseReleased( MouseEvent e ) {  // called after a button is released
       repaint();
      e.consume();
   }
   public void mouseMoved( MouseEvent e ) {  // called during motion when no buttons are down
      e.consume();
   }
   public void mouseDragged( MouseEvent e ) {  // called during motion with buttons down
     int mx = e.getX();
     int my = e.getY();

      vec.add(new MyShape(mx,my,new Color(0,255,0)));
      repaint();
      e.consume();
   }


}
```

It should draw circles at mouse drag but it didn't. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add the mouse listeners.

```
public void init()
{
    this.addMouseListener(this);
    this.addMouseMotionListener(this);
}
```

---

**Hint**: Try using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> - <kbd>Shift</kbd> - <kbd>F</kbd> in your IDE. Normally, it will beautify your code. (Eclipse and NetBeans support this)

Comment: The class implements `MouseListener`.